# Hibernate - Get entity's property without fetching the whole entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an object A connected to an object B with the @ManyToMany annotation.
The obj B has an Id and a name.
I would retrieve just those two properties without fetching the entire object, I will retrieve it later if I need it to not stress the memory.

I tried to use @AccessType("property") but it doesn't work (or maybe I use it in the wrong way :) )

I don't want to use the EAGER fetchType.

This is the @ManyToMany association:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @AccessType("property")
    @JoinTable(name = "C_CONTACT_USER_MANAGES_CONTACTS", catalog = "dbo", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_USER_ID_FK", nullable = false, updatable = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID_FK", nullable = false, updatable = true) })
    public Set<ContactTO> getManagedContacts() {
        return managedContacts;
    }

    public void setManagedContacts(Set<ContactTO> managedContacts) {
        this.managedContacts = managedContacts;
    }
```

where the contact user manage multiple contacts.

And this is the error I'm getting (the list of managed contacts need to be loaded at the beginning, so there isn't any session opened yet)

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.un.cdb.to.ContactUserTO.managedContacts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using a query? `SELECT user.managedContacts.id, user.managedContacts.name FROM ContactUserTO user`

Comment: You can navigate nested entities with JPQL. I haven't tested exactly this syntax, though.

Comment: I will try it asap, I'll let you know :)

Comment: Hi @beerbajay, I followed your advice and I succeeded to access to the set!

The code is

select contacts.contactId, contacts.lastName, contacts.firstName
from ContactUserTO contactUser
join contactUser.managedContacts contacts
where contactUserId := contactUserId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @beerbajay's advice I found the solution:

```
select contacts.contactId, contacts.lastName, contacts.firstName 
from ContactUserTO contactUser join contactUser.managedContacts contacts 
where contactUserId := contactUserId
```

Thanks for the help ;)